# Simulation satellite channel in Matlab

Tags: communication-satellite, simulation

Where can I find values for delays and pdp to simulate the satellite-ground channel?

PS 3GPP TS 36.116 document contains multi-path delay profiles used for the performance measurements in a multipath fading environment. Is there a similar profile for satellite channels?